# How to setup WITH queries with two aliases and selects

Tags: sql, oracle, join, common-table-expression

Using WITH construct at the beginning of a SQL, to perform a couple sub queries that are then available to several places in the body (subsequent) part of a query in Oracle.

Can you join or match up t2 with t1 in your example, i.e. translated to my code,

```
WITH t1 as (select * from AA where FIRSTNAME like 'Kermit%'),
     t2 as (select * from BB B join t1 on t1.ID = B.ID)
```

I think I'm pretty clear that t1 can be referenced inside of the 2nd segment of the WITH.

Are the two selects inside parenthesis pretty much full-fledged queries that can reference different tables, use whatever where conditions are needed?

I am not clear whether one can use JOIN to match up in this case records from AA and BB, or perhaps a different joining approach within the 2nd WITH clause. Some of the examples I have seen have a WHERE A=B down in the body of the select "below" the two WITH clauses.

The error I'm getting following these WITH declarations is the identifiers (field names) in t2 are not recognized, but rest of the SQL references from t1 just fine. It seems that the WITH syntax runs OK, but cannot access the results from the second WITH segment (t2).

Here is the whole non-working query.

```
with S as (select * from all_records where RESP_MGR like 'Smith%'),
     CHL as (select * from change_log CL JOIN S on S.SERVER_ID = CL.SERVER_ID)

select * from (
   select 
       SERVER_ID as ServerID,
       'Current Environment' as Event,
       SYSDATE as "Date",
       NEW_VALUE as "Data" 
   from CHL
   where OBJECT_DESCR = 'Production'
) 
where "Data" is not null
```

Oracle says,

```
 ORA-00904: "SERVER_ID": invalid identifier
 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: The way you described how "factored subqueries" (what goes in the WITH clause) should work is correct. If your query was EXACTLY like you wrote the made-up example, you wouldn't get any errors. Can you show the actual query that's not working - perhaps we can help point out what's wrong. (It is not your UNDERSTANDING of how it SHOULD work - that is perfectly fine.)

Comment: Hello mathguy and thanks.  I posted the whole code, and the error message.  The error reports on the line having the SERVER_ID reference right above the words "Current Environment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's an ambiguity matter. In

```
CHL as (select * from change_log CL JOIN S on S.SERVER_ID = CL.SERVER_ID)
```

there are two columns called `SERVER_ID` in `SELECT *`: `S.SERVER_ID` and `CL.SERVER_ID`. I guess Oracle aliases them something like `S_SERVER_ID` and `CL_SERVER_ID` in its result set.

An easy way to solve this would be a `USING` clause

```
CHL as (select * from change_log CL JOIN S using (SERVER_ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [Tom Kyte's explanation](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932):

> ANSI SQL has table references (correlation names) scoped to just one level deep

In other words, your main query (first level) would be able to reference that column, but since your subquery (second level) is more than one level deep, it is not able to reference the column, which is the reason you are receiving the error.

I don't know the structure of your tables, but I would think you don't really need the subquery, and could instead use something like this (air code):

```
with S as (select * from all_records where RESP_MGR like 'Smith%'),
     CHL as (select * from change_log CL JOIN S on S.SERVER_ID = CL.SERVER_ID)
select 
   SERVER_ID as ServerID,
   'Current Environment' as Event,
   SYSDATE as "Date",
   NEW_VALUE as "Data" 
from CHL
where OBJECT_DESCR = 'Production' and NEW_VALUE is not null
;
```

Comment: Great clarifying point, on the direct cause of my problem.  Thank you MJH.  My little code snippet above does have that enclosing SELECT and the subquery within it, this is a simplified excerpt of the actual code which requires that structure due to the complexity of the queries actually needed.  So unfortunately I may be "SOL" on the barrier to using WITH aliases and may be seeking other approaches.  I thank you for your answer!

Comment: No. The problem of too deep a level is not given in Dave's query. The outermost query accesses "Data" which is created in the second level. That second level query then accesses SERVER_ID, which exists twice in the third level. The level depth problem occurs in another situation, namely when you want to correlate a subquery with a value from two or more levels up. This is not given here.